# WebAudioAPI - change SampleRate in Windows definitions

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

My sampleRate in `AudioContext.SampleRate()` is always 48khz. Then I change the definitions in windows, going to "recording devices" and change there the SampleRate of the Mic. But, with any reason to happen, the `AudioContext.SampleRate()` remains the same. Why? This value is related only to the device and not with the windows definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio context sample rate is determined by the output device, not the input device. The input device is resampled to the output device rate.

Comment: I change the sample Rate in windows, but this time I made the change in speakers devices. And everything goes right. Thanks again @cwilso

Comment: No problem.  In the future, the sample rate will be selectable for the audiocontext, but I'd still expect the output device to drive the clock, so the input will always be resampled.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://github.com/taisel/XAudioJS/blob/master/resampler.js

```
var resampler = new Resampler(44100, 48000, 1, 2229);

function startUsermedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    recorder = audio_context.createScriptProcessor(2048);
    recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
    recorder.connect(audio_context.destination);
}

function recorderProcess(e) {
    var buffer = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var resampled = resampler.resampler(buffer);
}
```

*Note:

Creds for code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30032095/1501285*